# how to get HostName for Opposition CsRF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For Opposition CSRF I use Below Filter :

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext != null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer == null)
                throw new System.Web.HttpException("Invalid submittion !");
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Host.ToLower() != "www.mysite.com")
                throw new System.Web.HttpException("this form wasn't submitting from this site !");
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
```

but I want change `"mysite.com"` to daynamicly .

I dont want  use static string . how can I do it ?
If use this below code , it always `true`

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Host!= filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Host)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no reasons to implement your own system.

There is a build-in mechanism with the [`ValidateAntiForgeryToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute.aspx) attribute and [`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.antiforgerytoken.aspx) in the forms posting to the method.

[Here is](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/) a little manual.

You can add token to your page:

```
@using(Html.Form("UserProfile", "SubmitUpdate")) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <!-- rest of form goes here -->
}
```

And check it in your controller's method in a declarative way:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ViewResult SubmitUpdate()
{
    // ... etc
}
```

The actual page will looks like code below:

```
<form action="/UserProfile/SubmitUpdate" method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="saTFWpkKN0BYazFtN6c4YbZAmsEwG0srqlUqqloi/fVgeV2ciIFVmelvzwRZpArs" />
    <!-- rest of form goes here -->
</form>
```

You also can add salt to your token:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken("someArbitraryString")
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt="someArbitraryString")]
```